# Dynamically taking value from Resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

In my solution, I have a folder App_GlobalResources. 
In my folder App_GlobalResources, I have two files Lang.fr.resx and Lang.resx.

At run time, I want to decide which file should be loaded and take the text from that file

When I write the below code, it shows me as :

```
The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.

colName = GetLocalResourceObject( "ColumnNamePrefix_" + colName.Substring(0, colName.Length - 3) ).ToString();
```

Could anyone tell me, what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's in `App_GlobalResources` you want to use [`GetGlobalResourceObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149949.aspx).

There's an overload that takes a `CultureInfo`, and that's how you can specify either default (I'm assuming English?) or your French version. Should be something like:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ColumnNamePrefix_" + colName.Substring(0, colName.Length - 3),
    "Lang", culture);
```